# Actualizar userSettings en tiempo de ejecución C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Cree estos atributos en el App.config de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

E investigando encontré que cuando se cambia cualquiera de los dos valores de timeOutLS o de timeOutCR desde el archivo se puede hacer que el programa puede refrescar esos valores y leer los nuevos con esto:

```
string sectionName = "userSettings";

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);
```

Pero esto no me funciona, quiero saber si estoy haciéndolo mal o existe otra forma de leer el nuevo valor cambiado sin necesidad de cerrar y abrir el programa nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza estos usings:

```
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Xml;
```

Usa este fragmento de código:

```
    //Nombre de la variable que quieras cambiar
    string key= "timeOutLS";
    string value = "8";//valor

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string directory = string.Empty;
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;

    xmlDoc.Load(directory);
    XmlNode appSettingsNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/SymetryBusService.Properties.Settings");

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in appSettingsNode)
    {
        if (childNode.Name.Equals("setting"))
        {
            foreach (XmlNode item in childNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Attributes["name"].Value == key)
                    item.InnerText = value.ToString();
            }

            xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        }
    }
```

Espero que te ayude.

Saludos.